# Kibana Default Index pattern is changing automatically after being set for Multiple times

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

Initially observed there Duplicate index patterns are present in Kibana and it is due to the import of objects which are using different IDs for same Index pattern name. So we changed the Index pattern ID to an unique ID to resolve the Duplicate Index patters issue. But now when ever I set a Default Index pattern either in Index pattern settings or Advanced setting after some point of time the Default Index pattern is changing to some other ID. Suspected it might be issue with Importing saved objects but the timeline of saved objects Import and Kibana default index pattern ID change is not matching.

As a workaround we are setting default Index pattern ID from code itself. But the Default Index patter is getting changed automatically and also not following any specific timelines, it is just changing automatically.

Would like to know why Default Index Pattern changing Automatically to some other ID even after set to a specific ID.